# homestead 'File not found' on windows 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm trying to get vagrant and homestead running on windows 8.1.
I've installed vagrant and homestead.
This is my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/Donny/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: myawesomeproject.app
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/myawesomeproject/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

and in my hosts file i've added;

```
127.0.0.1 myawesomeproject.app
```

Now when I try to access myawesomeproject.app:8000 I get the error '404 Not found'.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj7Oa.png)
I have tried changing the 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file to 192.168.10.10, but no luck.
I am able to access the VM through `homestead ssh`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to point it to `192.168.10.10`, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Got it! Linux is case sensitive and you're telling him to share into `/home/vagrant/Projects`, but then you mapped the site folder to `/home/vagrant/projects/myawesomeproject/public`. Fix the `P` and run `vagrant provision`, that should fix it!